# Hibernate data truncation: Incorrect integer value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00& when trying to save a OneToMany Relation

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have two entities with this kind of relation

**EVENT**

```java
@Data
@Table(name = "Event", schema = "schema")
public class Event extends Loggable implements Serializable {
        
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;
            
  //   ....
    
  @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  List<RecurringPattern> recurringPatterns;
    
  private void setRecurringPatterns(List<RecurringPattern> children) {
     this.recurringPatterns = children;
  }
    
  public void addRecurringPattern(RecurringPattern child) {
     recurringPatterns.add(child);
     child.setEvent(this);
  }
```

**RECURRING PATTERN**

```java
@Data
@Table(name = "RecurringPattern")
public class RecurringPattern implements Serializable {
    
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Integer id;
    
   @Column(name = "eventId") <-- ManyToOne here has caused problems
   private Event event;

}
```

In a Controller in an "one shot" operation, I try to save at the same time an `Event` and his `RecurringPattern` child, reading the data from a Json.

```java
event = new Event();
recurringPattern = new RecurringPattern();
    
event.GetDataFromJson(...);
recurringPattern.GetDataFromJson(...);
event.addRecurringPattern(recurringPattern);
    
try {
   eventRepository.save(event);
}
catch(Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

With the debugger everything seems fine and no Exception is thrown during the `.save()` method.

But then I get this kind of error in the Stacktrace:

```
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect integer value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00&it.***.checklist.models.calendar.Event\xD9\x09\xD1\x95\xF9\xBF\x05F\x02\x00\x0FL\x00\x09createdByt\x00\x1' for column `schema`.`recurringpattern`.`eventId` at row 1
```

I really don't get it, is it something related to my annotations or the Utf encoding of the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should correct this:

```java
@Column(name = "eventId") <-- ManyToOne here has caused problems
private Event event;
```

to this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "eventId")
private Event event;
```

and this:

```java
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
List<RecurringPattern> recurringPatterns;
```

to this:

```java
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "event")
List<RecurringPattern> recurringPatterns;
```

See also [this section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional) of hibernate documentation.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is having this error, try to put the annotations on top of the getters instead of the private attributes